# Number is not coming is DropDownlist using loop

Tags: c#

I want to load number in dropdown list using `for` loop.

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String Mon;
            Mon = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;

            int noofday;

            if (Mon == "Feb")

                noofday = 28;
            else
                noofday = 31;

            for (int j = 1; j <= noofday; j++)
            {
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(j.ToString());
            }

        }
```

But dropdown is not getting number:

[image]

Comment: Is this ASP.Net? Have you debugged to ensure the event is being raised?

Comment: Your code has too many closing brackets, is that just a typing error?

Comment: Based on the name of your event, it's firing when DropDownList2 is changed, but it appears it should be firing when DropDownList3 is changed. You can spot such issues sooner if you give your controls proper names.

Comment: Just BTW: You should never do hard coded date logic in your code (IMHO). Why not use `DateTime` (or some library dedicated to handling dates/times)? For example, have you considered leap years?

Comment: @elgonzo You just modified the code, you should not do that.

Comment: @Esko, how would those two curly braces at the end of the code snippet be in any case relevant to the question?

Comment: Which DropDownList ist which? I'd suggest renaming them DropDownListYear, etc. Anyway if DropDownList2 is for days, then you are most propably using the wrong event handler. You could also use a calendar control instead.

Comment: This issue has been resolve i did enable auto postback on dropdown,,Thanks ALL